# Updating yaxis min/max bounds in an apexchart series

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, apexcharts

I'm using apexcharts and react to model a live updating price chart. As part of this chart, I would like to update the minimum and maximum bounds as new data from the series is rendered.

My thoughts are that I can define state for min and max bounds,

```
  let [min, setMin] = useState(9999)
  let [max, setMax] = useState(0)
```

set the state inside apexcharts **updated event** option (which *[fires when the chart has been dynamically updated either with updateOptions() or updateSeries() functions](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/)*) when the latest price from the series is above or below the current min/max.

```
  const options = {
      events: {
        updated: function(chartContext, config) {
          console.log(`update called! \n chartContext: ${chartContext.data.twoDSeries}`)
          let yaxis = config.config.yaxis[0]
          let latestPrice = chartContext.data.twoDSeries[chartContext.data.twoDSeries.length - 1]
          if(yaxis.min > latestPrice){
            setMin(latestPrice)
          }
          if(yaxis.max < latestPrice) {
            setMax(latestPrice)
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

and then plug in the min/max values into the yaxis option and return the chart

```
    yaxis: {
      title: { text: "Live updating chart" },
      labels: {
        formatter: val => val.toFixed(1)
      },
      min: min,
      max: max
    }
  };
  return <Chart type="candlestick" options={options} series={props.dataList} width = "1200" height = "600" />;
};
```

However this doesn't work very well and the updated state is not reliably getting passed to the y-axis. Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks!